I can't download magento sample data , i use 2.4.6 and php 8.1.2

My command line is still like it for a hour :))

Can you please share which command you are using to install sample the data.

It looks like you're facing an issue where the process of downloading the Magento sample data is stuck or taking too long. Let's break down what you can do to fix it, in simpler terms.
Step-by-Step Guide:
Why It's Stuck:
Sometimes, downloads get stuck because of a slow internet connection, or the server might be busy. There are a few things we can try to get it moving again.
Increase Timeout:
Magento might be giving up on the download too quickly. You can tell Magento to wait longer for the download to finish. Run this command:
        composer config -g process-timeout 2000

This increases the waiting time to help finish the download.
Check Internet & Server:
Ensure your internet connection is stable. If it’s slow, you can either try again later or switch to a faster connection.
Clear Cache:
Sometimes old data gets in the way. You can clear the cache to make things smoother. Use this command:
            composer clear-cache

Self-Update Composer:
Make sure you’re using the latest version of Composer (the tool you’re using to install Magento). Update Composer by running:
            composer self-update

Memory Issue:
If your server runs out of memory, it might cause the download to fail. You can increase the memory limit in PHP by editing the php.ini file. Look for memory_limit and set it to:
memory_limit = 2G
Then restart your server.
Try Again:
Once you’ve tried these steps, you can attempt to download the sample data again by running the same command:
        composer require magento/sample-data


Please do not use ChatGPT to submit content to this or any other Stack Exchange site.
